# What are the benefits of using Knockout in an ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working on  ASP.NET MVC 5 on a project. Previous developer who worked on that project used knockout.

Why would I need to use Knockout? The razor view engine does a pretty good job with 
@Html control. What i feel is if you are using jquery plugins it make more difficult for you to manage your application with knockout.

I am new to knockout.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, KO is not a replacement for the Jquery. It just helps you to provide design scalability and data-driven UI.

Benefits:
Anytime we can connect UI elements with data model. 
Easily create complex dynamic data model.
Automatically update UI when Data Model is changed, when UI is changed then Data Model is changed automatically.
Support event-driven programming model.
Extend custom behavior very easily. 
All main-stream browsers are supported (IE, FireFox, Crome, Safari)

I found the best result when I combined Knockout and Bootstrap with ASP.NET MVC with Razor view engine, to create a website with MVVM architecture.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.In our application we are using lot of table. these table need to have paging, sorting. If use only jquery and mvc i can easily use jqgrid plugin and easliy do the job.  but  with knockout it make more difficult to use available plugins like jqgrid, select2

Comment: Well I don`t know much about your application thus I can`t comment more but even with the KO basic jqgrid has been integrated. Have a look upon the link: https://github.com/CraigCav/Knockout-jqGridBinding. and if your application is needed full-fledged grid then you are right

Comment: @Mahesh > please see http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html to create your own binding for the plugins (jqgrid, select2) and use them like any other knockout bindings like click, value, and so on.

Comment: @LostCoder Do you have an example application?

Comment: It is portal application. every single page contains tables. those table need to have basic features such as sorting,filtering, paging. Some table need to have nested table. Is there any good plugin to support out of the box paging and filtering with knockout generated table.